# MVAPICH2 - supported network types

Tags: mpi, ethernet, infiniband, mvapich2

Can MVAPICH2 be installed on a normal ethernet network other than InfiniBand or other HPC networking technology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very first line on the [MVAPICH2](http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/overview/mvapich2/) web site reads:

> MVAPICH2 (MPI-3 over OpenFabrics-IB, OpenFabrics-iWARP, PSM, uDAPL and **TCP/IP**)

Then from the list of supported interfaces:

> - TCP/IP-CH3: The standard TCP/IP interface (provided by MPICH2) to work with a range of network adapters supporting TCP/IP interface. This interface can be used with IPoIB (TCP/IP over InfiniBand network) support of InfiniBand also. However, it will not deliver good performance/ scalability as compared to the other interfaces.

Therefore - yes.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. But at the configuration of MVAPICH, it fails giving an error that 'libibverbs' is not found.

Comment: Try configuring it without InfiniBand support. Or install the development headers for `libibverbs`.